# Warning: Rendering <Context.Consumer.Provider> is not supported and will be removed in a future major release in Next.js 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

## Problem

I tried to use `useRef` hook for accessing JSX, but I got these two errors when I checked the ref with `console log`

Here is what I was doing. I was using tailwind css

```js
'use client'

import Link from 'next/link'
import Logo from '@/logo.svg'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

const links = {
  About: '/',
  Project: '/project/list',
  Artist: '/artist/list',
}

type Menu = 'About' | 'Project' | 'Artist'

export function MenuItem({ content }: { content: Menu }) {
  const link = links[content]
  if (!link) {
    return <></>
  }
  return (
    <Link
      href={link}
      className="poppins mr-4 mt-4 block text-[#171616]/50 hover:text-[#171616] hover:opacity-100 lg:mt-0 lg:inline-block"
    >
      {content}
    </Link>
  )
}

export default function Navbar() {
  const menus: Menu[] = ['About', 'Project', 'Artist']
  const navRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(navRef)
  }, [navRef])
  return (
    <nav ref={navRef} className="flex flex-wrap items-center border-b border-[#171616]/30 bg-white px-40">
      <Link href="/" className="hidden lg:block">
        <Logo className="mb-[30px] mt-[30px]" width="151px" height="45px" color="#171616" />
      </Link>
      <div className="block flex flex-grow items-center">
        <div className="flex flex-grow justify-center gap-24">
          {menus.map((content, idx) => (
            <MenuItem key={idx} content={content} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="rounded-[40px] px-[36px] py-[16px] text-right text-[18px] leading-none text-[#171616]/50 hover:border-transparent hover:bg-[#7960BE]/75 hover:text-white">
          <Link href="/auth/login">Login</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

The first error was ...

```
Warning: Rendering <Context.Consumer.Provider> is not supported and will be removed in a future major release. Did you mean to render <Context.Provider> instead?
    at Navbar (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/components/Navbar.tsx:46:65)
    at ModalProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/context/ModalProvider.tsx:33:11)
    at App (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/app/App.tsx:12:11)
    at body
    at html
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:276:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:90:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:106:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:387:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:154:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:171:11)
```

and the second thing was

```
Warning: Rendering <Context.Consumer.Consumer> is not supported and will be removed in a future major release. Did you mean to render <Context.Consumer> instead?
    at Navbar (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/components/Navbar.tsx:46:65)
    at ModalProvider (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/context/ModalProvider.tsx:33:11)
    at App (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./src/app/App.tsx:12:11)
    at body
    at html
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:276:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:90:11)
    at commitHookPassiveMountEffects (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22022:7)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:106:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:387:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:154:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:171:11)
```

## I don't know why this is happening

Based on the log, I guessed this was related with my ModalProvider, but I didn't find any problem in it.

Here is my ModalProvider code

```js
'use client'

import { useReducer, createContext, ReactNode, Dispatch, useContext } from 'react'

export type ModalState = {
  type: 'default'
  isOpen: boolean
}

type Action = { type: 'OPEN' } | { type: 'CLOSE' }

type ToggleDispatch = Dispatch<Action>

export const ModalStateContext = createContext<ModalState | null>(null)
export const ModalSetterContext = createContext<ToggleDispatch | null>(null)

// reducer
function reducer(state: ModalState, action: Action): ModalState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'OPEN':
      return {
        ...state,
        isOpen: true,
      }
    case 'CLOSE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isOpen: false,
      }
    default:
      throw new Error('unhandled action')
  }
}

export function ModalProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { type: 'default', isOpen: false })

  return (
    <ModalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <ModalSetterContext.Provider value={dispatch}>{children}</ModalSetterContext.Provider>
    </ModalStateContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Cause I was using Next.js 13.4, I wrapped this provider with a client component like this.

```js
'use client'
import { ModalProvider } from '@/context/ModalProvider'
import ModalContainer from '@/components/modal/ModalContainer'
export default function App({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <ModalProvider>
      {children}
      <ModalContainer />
    </ModalProvider>
  )
}
```

I really want to know how to fix it...